# Video element stealing events from overlayed elements

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to create an simple overlay on a video element that displays some text, and a button.

However, when I try to add events such as click or mouseenter on elements in the overlay, the events are not triggered. I am using angular.

The events are detected if i use `pointer-events: none;` on the video, however this is not useful as we still need to be able to click on the video to pause etc.

This is my html snippet

```
<div class="overlay">
  <span (click)="test()" (mouseenter)="test()" (mouseleave)="test()">Click me</span>
</div>
<video></video>
```

And my CSS

```
.overlay {
  background-color: grey; 
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  top: 60px;
  margin-top: -60px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code sample to work with? Maybe as a StackBlitz sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give your `.overlay` a `z-index` of > 0 and it would work just fine:

```
.overlay {
  ...
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: oops, i could have sworn I tried this already. But thanks, this works